# Unable to store Json object in database Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, laravel

I am developing a billing table after create on billing button it is creating JSON object of every table cell array data and sending to controller through AJAX.

jQuery Code

```js
 $(".bill").click(function() {
  var iname_item=[];
  var qt_item=[];
  var price_item=[];
  var paying_item=[];
  var bal_item=[];

  $('.iname_item').each(function(){
    iname_item.push($(this).text());
  });

  $('.qt_item').each(function(){
    qt_item.push($(this).text());
  });

  $('.price_item').each(function(){
    price_item.push($(this).text());
  });

  $('.paying_item').each(function(){
    paying_item.push($(this).text());
  });

  $('.bal_item').each(function(){
    bal_item.push($(this).text());
  });

  var cn_iname_item=JSON.stringify(iname_item);
  var cn_qt_item=JSON.stringify(qt_item);
  var cn_price_item=JSON.stringify(price_item);
  var cn_paying_item=JSON.stringify(paying_item);
  var cn_bal_item=JSON.stringify(bal_item);                                
  alert(cn_iname_item);

  var datastring="item_iname="+cn_iname_item+"&item_qt="+cn_qt_item+"&item_price="+cn_price_item+"&item_paying="+cn_paying_item+"&item_bal="+cn_bal_item;

  $.ajax({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    type:'POST',
    url:'/billing',
    data:datastring,
    success:function(data){
      console.log(data);
    },
  });
});
```

How can I iterate this JSON data and store into database?

```php
array:5 [
  "item_iname" => "["Oats","Muesli"]"
  "item_qt" => "["2","5"]"
  "item_price" => "["500","300"]"
  "item_paying" => "["500","300"]"
  "item_bal" => "["0","0"]"
]
```

Comment: What is your controller doing? what's your database structure ?

Comment: right now contriller is getting only $request->all(); and json_decode the particular request like $iname=json_decode($request->get(item_iname),true);

Answer (score 0):

Several methods.

**Easiest:**

- create a text-column in your table (example: attribute "data"). Standard laravel stuff. I am sure you can do this.
- have your code do this:

> ```
> $object = new yourModel();
> $object->data = json_encode($array);
> $object->save();
> ```

**Next method, but better: attribute casting**

- create a text-column in your table. Same as above.
- add a default cast to your Model:

> protected $casts = ['data' => 'array'];

- have your code do this:

> ```
> $object = new yourModel();
> $object->data = $array;
> $object->save();
> ```

Be aware: this is pseudo code to give you an idea. Make sure you have correct code in your application.

More information about attribute casting in laravel: 
[laravel documentation about attribute casting](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting)

Comment: $iname=json_decode($request->get('item_iname'),true) ; im getting every $request data like this , now we have so many item_name obviously whats the next step? how to iterate all these requests and store into db, i already creates columns in my table for every cell like: item_name,item_qt,item_price,paid,item_bal

Comment: thats default php? do you need an example for that?